# Alternative adverb to "sectarianly"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is *sectarianly* an acceptable adverb in the following sentence?

> Northern Ireland is a **sectarianly** charged area of the world.

If not what can be used as an alternative adverb?

The word *sectarianly* is not listed at www.merriam-webster.com but mentioned at dictionary.com as a link to *sectarian*. In addition, the British National Corpus does not seem to have any results for it.

Comment: @Will Hunting Thanks Will, I mean that the society is charged emotionally by sectarian differences. Charged as in 'Charged with energy.' Not charged as in charged with a crime / accused etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I understand it, but I'm British and have lived with the Troubles all my life. It's an acceptable colloquialism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with trying to make an adverb out of *sectarian*. It just sounds horribly awkward. You could simply say

> Northern Ireland is charged with sectarian tensions.

I think you can lose "area of the world" since this information is already known by everyone. But if you feel the need to emphasize that fact, you could say

> Northern Ireland is an area of the world that is charged with sectarian tensions.

The key is to use *sectarian* as an adjective, not an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

When you Google the word *sectarianly* (as I am sure you did), there are a few hits, including a blog called [Sectarianly Yours](http://sectarianlyyours.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/sectarianly-yours/) and the definition you found.

I knew immediately what your sentence meant (there is much partisan or factional strife in Northern Ireland), so I think your sentence is grammatical and understandable.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with *religiously charged*.  You couldn't use *religiously divided*, I think, without implying that non-Christians were involved: but the tension is certainlty religiously based.